# UILabel text alignment is distorted after rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

Problematic scenario of my problematic label:

1. View screen in portrait mode

[image]

2. Press home button
3. Rotate device
4. view screen again

[image]

Here is the declaration of the button:
UIView *bottomButtons = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.width, kBottomButtonsHeight)];

```
    CGFloat buttonWidth = self.tableView.width/2.0;
    self.cancelButton = [[MobliButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonWidth, kBottomButtonsHeight)];
    self.cancelButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorFromHexString:@"B3B3B3"];
    [self.cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismiss) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.cancelButton setTitle:NLS(@"Cancel") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.cancelButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:16.0];
    self.cancelButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

    ....

    [self.tableView setTableFooterView:bottomButtons];
```

Comment: This seems wrong to me `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`

Comment: @Desdenova, what is your suggestion?

Comment: I'd try flexible left and bottom for cancel & flexible right and bottom for the done button.

Comment: @Desdenova. That is how it is: self.cancelButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;self.nextButtonView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Yours was the other way around. I would also add a flexible bottom margin to both of them just to be sure on both screen sizes.

```
self.cancelButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;

self.nextButtonView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Good luck.